# how to slow down the raising of windows (in windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, window-focus

I have several full screen windows that I like to keep open, but I don't want them raising (too fast) when I open a new window (from the task bar) because I have to move the mouse over them to get to the newly opened window, and in the process they come to the front and I can't get to the new window.  So, I would like to add a 5 second delay before a window is raised.  I like it getting focus quickly, but not raising.

Is there a way to configure Windows (10) to behave that way.  I could do that in X because I wrote my own window manager.

Alternately, if opening a window from the task bar, the mouse jumped into that window, that would probably suffice.

Another possibility.  Is it possible to tell Windows not to raise windows at all unless I click on them or do a menu action, e.g. go to the window title and click there or right-click or something else, so that I can focus on/in a window and type at it or click in it but not have it cover the screen (until I want it to).

Comment: "I don't want them raising (too fast) when I open a new window (from the task bar)"  <-- What does this mean? I do not think the concept you are looking for exists in Windows 10.  Things on the task bar can be reviewed by hovering with the mouse and then actioned by clicking with the most. There is no time delay here.

Comment: It's not about the task bar part of the action.  I open the new window using the task bar and it pops up on my screen, but as I move my mouse from the task bar to where the new window is, it moves across these windows that cover all the screen (except the task bar) and these windows get raised, covering the window I just opened.  I have to close them (which I don't want to do) to get to the newly opened window.  If I could move across them without raising them, it would make my life easier.

Comment: The only thing I can see here is the small Window that pops up and down as I hover over the task bar. That is a new Windows 10 feature and causes new Windows to show up temporarily. But nothing really happens until we action an App and then everything that was on the screen stays at the same place.

Comment: You are misunderstanding, the task bar part works fine.  It's just when I move my mouse out of the task bar to the window the task bar opened when I run the app, my mouse crosses over these other windows and these windows get raised, because I don't have click-to-type set and by moving my mouse through them they get focus and thus get raised.  I want to delay when they get raised like you can in X.  Or I want opening the window to jump the mouse into it.  That would be ok too.

Comment: I really cannot figure out what you are trying to accomplish or what delay you want. I have no idea.

Comment: Ok, I have on my screen a huge Emacs window.  That's what I use almost all the time.  It covers the whole screen except the task bar.  I go to the task bar and open this Google chrome window.  It is small.  It doesn't cover the whole screen.  Now, as I am moving my mouse to this window.  It leaves the task bar, and before reaching this window and enters the Emacs window, because that window covers the space between the task bar and the newly opened window.  That causes the Emacs window to raise covering up this window.  I want to find a way to keep that from happening.

Comment: On X windows, you can set a delay on when a window is raised as the mouse enters it to keep this from happening.  You can also configure it so that if you do something that pops up a window, so that the mouse is moved into that window.  Either piece of functionality would solve my problem.  I'm looking for the equivalent setting in Windows.  So I can have my Emacs window cover the whole screen, but when I pop up a window, move to that window without getting it covered up.

Comment: The standard behavior on Windows (and everywhere, basically) is to focus inactive windows when you click on them, not hover. The easiest solution would be to undo whatever you did to achieve what you're describing.

Comment: Yes, I know what I did to enable the behavior.  I turned off click-to-type.  I don't want to have to click in my Emacs windows to type into them.  I want to just move my mouse into them (or close whatever window was on top of them) and start typing. And I want them to be full-screen all the time.  But, I want to be able to popup windows over them (e.g. from the taskbar) and then work for short periods of time in those windows, without the Emacs window coming to the front.  I can do that on Linux and Macs.  I just want to figure out how to do it in Windows....

Comment: Actually, I have some programs. e.g. Desktop sidebar and the Windows8 Gadget pack.  That both park themselves on the desktop and don't autoraise (until you actually click on them).  That's the functionality I want for Emacs.

Comment: @intel_chris That's not a feature [mousing over a window makes it active] that's enabled by default _(I'm unsure where the setting exists in Windows)_. Do you have any programs from Stardock installed?

Comment: Turning off click-to-type make a window active simply by entering it--it took me a while to find the windows menu that enables that.  That's the behavior I want.  I just don't want it raised just because it is active.  I want it to remain partially hidden, just be active.